# Определить параметры сисистемного вызова на Golang

Tags: golang, syscall

В https://4gophers.ru/articles/strace/ представлен проект, в котором написан код `starce` на Go, но я не смог разобраться, как получить параметры которые передаются в системный вызов, если конкретнее, нужно понять какой файл пытается открыть системный вызов open
 В конце статьи вроде есть ссылка но она не рабочая.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй взять этот же сайт [из вебархива](http://web.archive.org/web/20181225072814/http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/).

Но вообще тут правильнее заходить с дргугого боку.
Любой сискол в Linux концептуально "состоит" из двух вещей:

1. Раскладка номера сисколла и его аргументов (если есть) согласно правилам так называемого "platform ABI".

   Смотри ответы [в этом треде](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133812/720999).
2. Собственно аргументы.

Первое всегда одинаково для всех сисколлов, а второй кусок информации добывается из мануалов на сисколлы.

Ещё, конечно, нужно знать правила, по которым *типы* аргументов должны передаваться в сискол.

Чтобы не заморачиваться с попытками догадаться, как там и что, проще всего посмотреть сорцы Go.
Конкретно там следует смотреть файлы, названные `z*_linux_${GOARCH}*.go`.